# Flask Class Based Views - Polymorphism

Tags: python, flask, polymorphism, django-class-based-views

I've a class-based view as follow:-

```
class MoviesList(MethodView):

    def get(self):
        return 'MoviesList'

    def get(self,pk):
        return pk

movies.add_url_rule('/movies/', view_func=MoviesList.as_view('movies_by_title'))
movies.add_url_rule('/movie/<pk>/', view_func=MoviesList.as_view('movie_details_by_id'))
```

When I hit `/movie/pk/` endpoint it says,
`TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'`. As per the polymorphism concept, it should automatically detect which function to route.

Why is this happening? Also, how can I achieve the same functionality, ie without making another class, how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python does not support method/function overloading. You can only define one `get` method and provide defaults for optional arguments:

```
class MoviesList(MethodView):

    def get(self, pk=None):
        if pk is None:
            return 'MoviesList'
        return pk
```